# clipsToBounds only verticaly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mask

I would like to be able to set `clipsToBounds` at `NO` for an `UIView` but only with the horizontal component.

My content will be displayed on left / right even if it's too large but top / bottom will not be displayed beyond the container's height.

Should I use `maskToBounds` layer property and add a specific mask ?

Comment: Why dont you use UIScrollView such that it can have big content horizontally or vertically and not otherwise. You could set contentSize and configure it any way you like it.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by asking yourself why you think you need this. If you want to display the horizontal content when `clipsToBounds` is YES, why not make the view big enough horizontally? It can go right off the screen on both sides, no problem. A view that is visible when it is not inside its superview is usually a very bad idea in any case (for example, the user can see it but can't touch it, which is usually undesirable and confusing).

Otherwise, this is going to be a very tricky problem. You will probably need to put another view above your view and another view below it, to cover the content that sticks out above and below your view. Crude but effective.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIView's `mask` property. [See documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622557-mask)

The mask view's width can be maximal, and the height can be the same as the view itself.

`maskToBounds` needs to be false in this case.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `mask` property effectively masks a bounded area of the view, so if you are trying to mask a view whose bounds change to reveal new content (i.e. a scroll view) this will not work because all the content outside the bounded area of the mask will be not be visible (i.e. the mask will not scroll with the scroll view by default).